# Creating buffers using JSTS + ES6 modules not working

Tags: javascript, buffer, jts-topology-suite, react, jsts

Creating a buffer from a Point or other Geometry objects in JSTS seems to be quite simple when reading the documentation, but still I can't produce a buffer from a Point in my React application.

Let me first tell that I'm using 'create-react-app' boilerplate generator and I have intalled JSTS like this:

> npm install --save jsts

Following this [JSTS + ES6 example](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/jsts-es6-example/blob/master/es6-examples/buffer.js) I came up with this code:

```
import extend from 'jsts/extend'
import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader';
import GeoJSONWriter from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONWriter';
import Geometry from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry';
import Coordinate from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Coordinate';
import {BufferOp} from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer';


// Add support for Geometry.buffer
extend(Geometry.prototype, {
    buffer: function () {
        return BufferOp.bufferOp(this, arguments);
    }
});


class Demo extends Component {


  bufferTest() {
    let reader = new GeoJSONReader();
    let writer = new GeoJSONWriter();

    let json = {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -58.435420989990234,
          -34.60650846219738
        ]
      };

    let pt = reader.read(json);
    let buffered = pt.buffer(40); // Will crash
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> RuntimeException: inconsistency in rightmost processing

I also created individual Coordinate and Geometry objects and tried to buffer the geometry using using a BufferOp instance and many other things with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote to the JSTS dev list asking about this issue and they told me to *"Avoid using extend/hacks as in the third party example"* and to instead use the BufferOp directly.

This is one way you can use **BufferOp** "directly" when you install JSTS from NPM and using ES6 modules (in this case I use the GeoJSON parser/reader):

```
import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader';
import GeoJSONWriter from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONWriter';
import {BufferOp} from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer';

let reader = new GeoJSONReader();
let writer = new GeoJSONWriter();
let json = {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -58.435420989990234,
      -34.60650846219738
    ]
  };
let spPoint = reader.read(json);
let spBuffer = BufferOp.bufferOp(spPoint, 0.2);
let polyGeoJSON = writer.write(spBuffer);
```